# Angular function return value

Tags: angular

In my angular project, I have a following setup:

**API.ts**: API functions to get data

```
...
export class dataAPI {
   info: any = null;

   getDataFromAPI(name){
     this.http.get(name)...
       .subscribe(data =>{
          this.info = data;  //This will have returned data
       }
   }  
}
```

**Main.ts**: Main page ts file where the API function is used

```
  import { dataAPI }  from '../API.ts';

  @Component({
     templateUrl: 'main_page.html'
  }) 

  export class mainPage{      
      returnedData: any;

      constructor(public myAPI: dataAPI){};

      ngOnInit(){
          this.returnedData = this.myAPI.getDataFromAPI('steve'); //????
      }        
  }
```

**main_page.html**: Need to show the returned data from API function

```
 <div class="main" *ngIf="returnedData">
     {{returnedData}}
 </div>
```

**Question**

From `API.ts` file, `this.info` will need to somehow passed onto `main.ts`. How do I do this? Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the output of this code ?

Comment: Why not return an Observable from service function and subscribe from it at your component? refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45652646/get-string-value-from-observablestring-in-typescript-and-angular/45652811#45652811

Comment: Seems like you are trying to return data from subscribe, which is not possible, so it's probably a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39295854/angular-2-how-to-return-data-from-subscribe)

Comment: Don't subscribe from the service. **Return** the observable, and subscribe in the component, or in the view using the async pipe.

Comment: The data returned is like a paragraph or phone number. Because there are many occasions and in many different files that I need to use the same api, I though I would make a function that I can use in multiple files.

Comment: Yes, that is the purpose of a service ... to share functionality across many places in the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**

I would do something like this

```
getDataFromAPI(name){
   //do not subscribe in this service! Return the observable.
    return this.http.get(name)...

   }
```

And in your `mainPage`

```
export class mainPage{      
      returnedData: any;

      constructor(public myAPI: dataAPI){};

      ngOnInit(){
         this.myAPI.getDataFromAPI('steve')
          .subscribe( data=>{
             this.returnedData = data; //SUBSCRIBE HERE
           }); 
      }        
  }
```

**Option 2**
Almost the same with option 1, but using an async pipe like this

```
export class mainPage{      
      returnedData$ : Observable<any>;

      constructor(public myAPI: dataAPI){};

      ngOnInit(){
         this.returnedData$ = this.myAPI.getDataFromAPI('steve');
      }        
  }
```

And in your template

```
<div class="main">
     {{ returnedData$ | async)}}
 </div>
```

**Option 3**
Here's another option and something that I would not recommend. Since you declare the service as public, you can use it as well in your template like this directly .

```
 <div class="main" *ngIf="myAPI.info">
    {{returnedData$ | async}}
 </div>
```

and declare your `info` as public in your service.

Comment: But NOTE: The above will only work if API.ts is a service. It's not clear from the OP that it is a service and not just a simple class.

Comment: @DeborahK thank you for commenting. I didn't notice that. I just assumed that it is a service. I agree that the question was not clear whether it was from a service or class

Answer (score 2):

Starting here may be helpful: https://angular.io/guide/http

Note that the sample code in the Angular docs does not yet show the "best practice" of using a service for the Http calls. But it does explain how http works and returns an observable to your code.

Here is an example service that returns a product. You can adjust this to meet your needs:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

import { IProduct } from './product';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
    private _productUrl = './api/products/products.json';

    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

    getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
        return this._http.get<IProduct[]>(this._productUrl)
            .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
        // in a real world app, we may send the server to some remote logging infrastructure
        // instead of just logging it to the console
        let errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is: ${err.message}`;
        console.error(errorMessage);
        return Observable.throw(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

And here is the component code that calls the service, receiving the data:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { IProduct } from './product';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './product-list.component.html'
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
    products: IProduct[] = [];
    errorMessage = '';

    constructor(private _productService: ProductService) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._productService.getProducts()
                .subscribe(products => this.products = products;,
                           error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
}
```